# Facebook Tutorial > Secure Page Tab URL requirements on October 1, 2011

Tags: facebook, canvas

I was wondering what this information means exactly:

October 1: All Canvas apps must process signed_request (fb_sig will be removed) and obtain an SSL certificate (unless you are in Sandbox mode).

Does anybody have more detailed information on what will happen on the 1st october and the tutorial about how we should switch to secure page tab URL? Will all the applications be unaccessible if we don't do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

facebook will not allow to add a new app that doesn't have a secure tab url (https)

if facebook will remove all old apps that do not have a secure tab url is not known at the moment.

a tutorial is not needed, the only thing you have to do is to provide https to your apps, 
in the apps settings.

there are a lot of free ssl certificate providers out there - or maybe your host provides ssl to your webspace.

http://tinyurl.com/3oqxutj